# Why does Qt3DWindow on rare instances not render a scene and instead projects other parts of the GUI onto the window?

Tags: qt, graphics, 3d, qt3d

This is a rare bug, but sometimes when I start my Qt app the qt3d window which hosts my scene is blank (without any of my models), except the window itself seems to be bugged because it will mirror other parts of the GUI if I shift between tabs. So instead of my scene appearing in the window it'll contain information and widgets from another tab that's located in the same area as the window on a different tab.

This doesn't occur very often, which makes the bug hard to replicate. Has anyone else seen this behavior before or maybe it's the way I'm setting up the Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow?

```
Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow* view = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow();
view->defaultFrameGraph()->setClearColor(QColor(0,0,0));

view->setRootEntity(CreateScene());

// embed 3D Window in Widget
QWidget* container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view);
ui->verticalLayout_visualizer->addWidget(container);
```

Comment: This happened for me only when I forgot to add a `QClearBuffers` node. Since you are using the default frame graph this should not happen. Could be that this is a bug within Qt3D.

Comment: Has the bug been reported?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an actual bug in the first place, so no idea ;)

Comment: Have you continued to get the error and would you recommend shifting to another way to establish a frame graph?